# Translate SPARQL to SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sparql, rdf, rdfs

I would like to know if there is a way to **obtain** the **SQL** query starting **from** a **SPARQL** query.

For example, I have this SPARQL query:

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX ub: <http://www.lehigh.edu/~zhp2/2004/0401/univ-bench.owl#>
SELECT ?X   
WHERE {
    ?X rdf:type ub:GraduateStudent .
    ?X ub:takesCourse <http://www.Department0.University0.edu/GraduateCourse0>
}
```

I would like to obtain something like this (the triples are stored in a table **triples(subject, predicate, object)**:

```
SELECT subject
FROM triples
WHERE predicate = "<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type>"
AND object = "<http://swat.cse.lehigh.edu/onto/univ-bench.owl#GraduateStudent>"
AND subject IN (
    SELECT subject
    FROM triples
    WHERE predicate = "<http://swat.cse.lehigh.edu/onto/univ-bench.owl#takesCourse>"
    AND object = "<http://www.Department0.University0.edu/GraduateCourse0>"
)
```

or

```
SELECT subject
FROM triples
WHERE predicate = "<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type>"
AND object = "<http://swat.cse.lehigh.edu/onto/univ-bench.owl#GraduateStudent>"

INTERSECT

SELECT subject
FROM triples
WHERE predicate = "<http://swat.cse.lehigh.edu/onto/univ-bench.owl#takesCourse>"
AND object = "<http://www.Department0.University0.edu/GraduateCourse0>"
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: that is impossible because this needs a specified SPARQL to SQL mapping  - I mean, this all depends on how the data is modelled in terms of SQL tables which is totally open. For a simple SQL table with columns `s,p,o` it would be indeed trvial at least for BGPs - it's takes more effort for things like `optional`, etc. - start with the SPARQL algebra and then write the translation

Comment: or just use a OBDA tool instead of reinventing the wheel

Comment: @UninformedUser Once I managed to have the algebra, then what should be the next step? I mean, there is a tool or an algorithm to use?

Comment: I'm not aware of a dedicated tool. I know from some tools that they did it under the hood, i.e.e somewhere in their source code. Basically all approaches that want to bring SPARQL to some framework that does only have native SQL support usually rewrite their SPARQL query to SQL, but then it's just somewhere tightly integrated in the code, i.e. not really usable as a dedicated Java package.

Comment: Clearly, traversing the algebra is simple, for Java you could use Apache Jena and traverse the algebra tree quite nicely and just add the SQL part. As I said before, for basic graph patterns this is easy, for each triple pattern you could generate a subquery, and in a post-processing step you could create the join clause for the shared variables.

Comment: May I ask for which SQL system you want to do it? And if so why a SQL based system instead of using a RDF triple store?

Comment: I am evaluating the possibility to use Spark and columnar storage techniques to store and query RDF graph efficiently and in a distributed way

Comment: there are already plenty of research papers regarding SPARQL on Apache Spark and Apache Flink - many of them did more or less the same stuff, try several DB partitioning schemes and then convert to SQL which can be used and optimized by those frameworks. From my point of view this topic is already done completely - there can't be anything new. If you just want to use of of those approaches, why not trying them?

Comment: There are a number of solutions (open source or otherwise) that let you write a mapping in R2RML, then either query the "virtual" graph as mapped from the relational database or migrate the relational content onto a graph database. You won't see the SQL query, all that's handled "behind the scenes".

Answer (score 0):

Apache Jena used to provide SQL storage : see https://github.com/apache/jena/tree/main/jena-sdb on how to get the old code. It translates basic graph patterns using JOIN and OPTIONAL with LEFT JOIN.

It has its own database layout with RDF terms in a dictionary. There was also a simple scheme with strings and a single triples table - that is not efficient in practice. See also the very old "RDB" Jena storage which was in the pre-Apache project.

There are also various papers on the web discussing this topic.

Comment: Juan Sequeda's Ph.D dissertation is the definitive work in this area: https://repositories.lib.utexas.edu/handle/2152/30537